# Como obter gênero de um usuário do Google em um app utilizando Firebase?

Tags: android, google, firebase, autenticação

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android nativo e a forma de autenticação é pelo perfil do Google. Gostaria de obter o gênero de cada usuário, no momento do signup, para verificar se é homem ou mulher. É possível fazer isso?

Nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249043/firebase-auth-get-additional-%20%20user-info-age-gender) fiquei sabendo que o próprio Firebase não dá suporte para o acesso ao gênero, então acredito que deve ser direto no Android.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33906880/7762411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na própria pergunta que você mencionou é exemplificado a `AsyncTask` necessária para pegar o gênero do usuário utilizando a [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)

Basicamente você envia para essa `AsyncTask` a conta que realizou o login através do `GoogleSignInAccount` para obter um objeto de `Person` e então dar um `profile.getGenders()` que retorna a lista de gêneros do usuário.

No `onPostExecute` você itera a lista para obter o valor real do gênero.

```
class GetGendersTask extends AsyncTask<GoogleSignInAccount, Void, List<Gender>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Gender> doInBackground(GoogleSignInAccount... googleSignInAccounts) {
        List<Gender> genderList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            //Redireciona a URL para aplicações web.
            // Pode ser deixada em branco.
            String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

            // Troca o código de autorização pelo token de acesso
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    httpTransport,
                    jsonFactory,
                    getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_id),
                    getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_secret),
                    googleSignInAccounts[0].getServerAuthCode(),
                    redirectUrl
            ).execute();

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(
                        getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_id), 
                        getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_secret)
                    )
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .build();

            credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

            People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("My Application Name")
                    .build();

            // Obtem o perfil do usuário
            Person profile = peopleService.people().get("people/me").execute();
            genderList.addAll(profile.getGenders());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return genderList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Gender> genders) {
        super.onPostExecute(genders);
        // Itera entre a lista de Gêneros para
        // obter o valor do gênero (masculino, feminino, outro)
        for (Gender gender : genders) {
            String genderValue = gender.getValue();
        }
    }
}
}
```